Would it be possible to adjust the scoring on questions to behave like those in www.stackoverflow.com?
When questions asked on stack overflow have their score clicked, one can see the up and down votes. This seems like a reasonable behavior. Would it be possible to implement the same thing on chinese.stackoverflow.com?

It's a privilege that you haven't earned yet. At 750 reputation, you can see vote counts.
